# is there any fix for flowplayer to work in android 3.1

Tags: css, video, html5-video, flowplayer

Flowplayer is not working in android 3.1 but works fine in android 4.1 version.

I have gone through the forums and found that by using:

```
flowplayer.conf = { engine: /android/.test(navigator.userAgent) ? "flash" : "html5" };
```

It should work. But still I am unable to resolve my problem.

I would like to know if there is any fix for this to work in android 3.1 version?

Comment: Have you checked on their forums/Support?

Comment: I have gone through the forums and found that by using:
flowplayer.conf = {
  engine: /android/.test(navigator.userAgent) ? "flash" : "html5"
};
it should work.

But still I am unable to resolve my problem.